Any idea how to stack two PCBs that can work independently
This is my first time ever doing PCB stuff :D
I have two L-shaped PCBs that will stack on top of each other. The connectors would stack on each other so that it can either:

Be used with both top and bottom by having a wire to board connector plug into the connector on the top

Or the top layer could be taken off and then the wire to board connector would just connect to the bottom layer connector.


I've attached my schematic and layout. I'd like to connect the two boards so they use the same connector. Then the wire connector can come in and attach on the top side if both are being used, or just the bottom side if the top is taken off the pins.




An answer already suggests board-to-board connectors. This is the way to go for a finished product. However, for prototypes, I am personally a huge fan of using cables (mostly jst picoblades or 100mil jumpers, but that's personal preference). The advantage of cables is that they can easily be probed and rearanged. Plus they can't create hyperstatismes (i.e. mechanical stress) which you need to be careful about with connectors.

What you are looking for is a board to board connector, check a distributor like mouser or digikey for the pitch and spacing height you want. You can also get 0.1" headers that are male on both ends so you could just solder the boards together if you don't want a connector.
Another way to do this is with 0.1" headers that are very long and have both male and female ends to stack PCB's, simmilar to arudino hats.

(AOL) Keyword might be bottom entry?

a stacking board to board connector.

Thank you for the advice guys, this is my first time doing any sort of pcb and all that stuff ever, just kinda thrown into the deep end and learning alot so far. will try these ideas and thanks. loving it so far!
